# Powershell script to change locked for editing to sharepoint\system status, ID not found?

Tags: 2010, list, powershell, document

I am trying to target a file to change the check out status.  So I can delete it.  SharePoint Management does not work.  Manage Content & Structure does not work.  So I am trying PowerShell.  However it does not like my `$item` value of 329 which SP claims is the ID value of the particular Doc.

```
    param (
    [string]$url,
    [string]$list,
    [int]$item

)
$url = "http://MyCollection/MySite/MyList"
$list = "Business Screening"
$item = 329
$w = get-spweb $url
$l = $w.lists[$list]
$i = $l.GetItemById($item)
$s = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($w.site.id, $i.File.LockedByUser.UserToken)
$w = $s.OpenWeb($w.id)
$l = $w.lists[$list]
$i = $l.GetItemById($item)
$i.File.ReleaseLock($i.File.LockId)
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Error is NullValueException on GetItemById

Answer (score 1):

If that is the error, I think your `$l` is `null`, meaning that your are not getting a reference to the list!

```
$list = "Business Screening"
$item = 329
$w = get-spweb $url
$l = $w.lists[$list]
```

should probably be

```
$list = "Business Screening"
$item = 329
$w = get-spweb $url
$l = $w.Lists.TryGetList($list) #this finds list by title
```

Comment: Should that not be `Lists.TryGetList([$list])`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I encountered same error on line 11 char 20.  After adding square brackets I got make sure assembly is loaded.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: No it should not be with brackets. What line is line 11?

Comment: Line 11 is as you are pointing out, sorry if I sound like I'm dismissing the help I'm asking for, I was under the impression `[]` were needed for names with spaces?  This must be incorrect yeah?  Relatively new to me.

Comment: No need for brackets since you have saved in in the variable

Answer (score 1):

A great tool I used when running into the "file locked for editing" issue was using the SPUnlock web part this just works. I've used this web part numerous time so unlock files for deleting. All you have to do is..

- Download SPUnlockSandbox.wsp from 
  https://spunlockfiles.codeplex.com/
- Upload  SPUnlockSandbox.wsp to SP Site Collection Solution Gallery
- Activate solution from solution gallery
- Confirm above step activate a  sitecollection feature
  "SPUnlockSandbox_Feature1"
- Navigate to you site or any subsite  where and add webpart "SPFile
  Unlock"  to any page

Hope this helps :)

Comment: +1 for the useful tool.  I believe this will solve my problem but for the purpose of the question at hand, I want to fully understand why my script isn't working or I won't learn anything.  Been pulled in another direction by management for now.  This is pending my answer.  Gonna further pursue Roberts pointers.  Thanks though :-)

Comment: Gotcha...I did some intense googleing and didnt find much. I would love to find out the reason as well!